# Is there a way to determine if a single SharePoint list item matches a SPQuery/SPView?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, spview

The standard 'Alerting' feature in SharePoint allows you to only send out an alert if the item appears in a specified view.

I'm wanting to apply similar logic in a custom workflow (c#).

Given a SPListItem and SPView/SPQuery does anybody know if there is an effective* way to see if the item falls into that view / matches the query?

*effective meaning, not just running the query then looping through to find the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had an idea however, if I adapt the idea discussed in the answer to this question [How to query the SPView object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661865/how-to-query-the-spview-object).

If I modify the query to execute all the filters from the view, but also add in a clause where ID equals the ID of my item, I will either get 1 result back or 0, then I can just check the count.

Performance wise I'm not sure which is more efficient between Mathieu's suggestion and this idea?

I will investigate tomorrow...

**UPDATE**
My technique was effective. I would like to think (from a design point of view) that the ID check occurring on the DB side rather than via an XML query, would be more efficient.

**Thanks all the same for your suggestion Mathieu.**

Answer (score 0):

I have not come across such a method on SPListItem, SPQuery, ... that has such functionality.
Checking if the current item is in the returned collection doesn't seem such a bad idea. But instead of looping through all the items I would use a LINQ query to help you out. Something like this:

```
itemCollection.Cast<SPListItem>().Any(i => i.ID.Equals(yourItem.ID));
```

Where "itemCollection" is the collection of items you got from the query or the view. and "yourItem" is the item you want to check if it's in the colleciton.